# how to retrieve array value using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to retrieve array value.
This is my array value:

overlay.txt:

```
{"title":"sss","description":"sss","code":"sss"}
{"title":"trtr","description":"trtr","code":"tyrytr"}
{"title":"ret54","description":"56tr","code":"ty76"}
{"title":"rgfdg","description":"dfgdfg","code":"dfgdfg"}
{"title":"asfafdsf","description":"sdfsdf","code":"sdfsdfsdf"}
```

This is my code: but this is not working.why?
How to retrieve value from overlay.txt file.
I did not get all title value.
I do not known how to get title value from overlay.txt
The $title is showing empty.
Where I want to change in my code to get $title value.

```
    $info = array();
    $folder_name = $this->input->post('folder_name');
    $info['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
    $info['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
    $info['code'] = $this->input->post('code');
    $json = json_encode($info);
    $file = "./videos/overlay.txt";
    $fd = fopen($file, "a"); // a for append, append text to file
    fwrite($fd, $json);
    fclose($fd); 
    $filecon = file_get_contents('./videos/overlay.txt', true);
    $this->load->view('includes/overlays',$filecon);

    //overlays page;
    foreach($filecon as $files)
    {
        $title=$files['title'];
        echo $title;
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about "this is not working".

Comment: I think you are mixing things. Your json content is sent to php by ajax? The "not working" means that `$json` is null?

Comment: ok.how to retrive value from overlay.txt file.send me php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make overlay.txt fully json format:

```
[
  {"title":"sss","description":"sss","code":"sss"},
  {"title":"trtr","description":"trtr","code":"tyrytr"},
  ...
]
```

and try this:

```
$raw = file_get_contents('./videos/overlay.txt', true);
$this->load->view('includes/overlays', array("filecon" => json_decode($raw)));
```

overlay page:

```
<?php
foreach($filecon as $files) {
    echo $files['title'];
}
?>
```

If you want to use `$filecon` in view file, 
set an array which has the key "filecon" in `$this->load->view()`'s second argument.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: This is very basic pattern. I think you should check each of process is fine or not. file_get_contents is OK? Setting simple variables in $this->load->view() works fine?

Comment: u see my code:this is correct or not?   $jsonObjects = file('./videos/overlay.txt');
foreach ($jsonObjects as $json) {
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$prints= $array['title'];
echo $prints;
}

Answer (score 1):

You're *encoding* your array to JSON, so at some point you need to *decode* it again into a PHP array. Since you actually have several JSON objects in the file, you need to decode each one individually. *Assuming* it's always one JSON object *per line*, this'll do:

```
$jsonObjects = file('overlay.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($jsonObjects as $json) {
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $array['title'];
    ...
}
```

This will very quickly break if there are line breaks within the serialized JSON, e.g.:

```
{"title":"ret54","description":"foo
bar","code":"ty76"}
```

That way of storing the data is not very reliable.

Comment: Can you try to be more precise? "Does not work" is *not* a problem description a programmer uses.